# How to install TWRP?

Tags: twrp

I'm a very beginner and I read some info about ADB tool and other articles about flashing ROM, rooting and things like that. I would like to install TWRP recovery on my phone using ADB tool.

I did the steps in this [web page](https://rootmygalaxy.net/install-twrp-recovery-via-fastboot/). It showed on the mobile screen that some data or files are successfully transferred (As far as I remember).

Now, when I enter the recovery mood, it's the same screen (same software) that appears before installing TWRP.

Why doesn't the  TWRP interface open? The link said "Done!!! Now you should have TWRP on your device" but I don't know how to open it on my phone.

Phone type: Techno W4

Comment: Did you boot immediately into TWRP afyer flashong or did you go to the system first?

Comment: first of all, you can not install a twrp.img on "any device" - you must find and download TWRP recovery for Tecno W4 (which is not official supported!) after `fastboot flash recovery twrp.img` type `fastboot boot twrp.img` then swipe to modify system (this will rename recovery-from-boot.p and make the twrp install permanent). second, you need to install "dm-verity disabler zip" to make your phone bootable again

Comment: https://mega.nz/#!oDIAyYzD!FwF0J3uLjjFfxETu6ylPwko82bUWE79Ex8uWG0-JeDk

Comment: @BoLawson Thank you so much for your suggestion. I used the file provided by After I wrote "Fastboot reboot", the phone restarted. I pressed the "Volume Up" button while restarting to boot into recovery mode. It works!

Comment: @alecxs Thank you so much for giving me this useful link. It works :) I also did what BoLawson said and I booted immediately into recovery mode after installation.